# Adding whole datanode to HDFS

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

My question could seem naive but I would like to know if I can add the all of contents of one whole node to HDFS.

I can run a program on one of datandodes but I would like to to be able to run it through HDFS as well.

Comment: Your code would need to be able to read from HDFS, not just the local filesystem of a datanode if you wanted it to run "in Hadoop".

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.